# Using simple sockets in a client/server in Python - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm making a simple Python script using sockets. This is my client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "172.31.26.54"
port = 1337
print("Attempting to connect...")
s.connect((host, port)) 
print("Connected. Now receving data from host.")
print s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

This is my server code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
print(host)
port = 1337
s.bind((host, port))

s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'recived connection from ', addr
    c.send("Thank you for connecting. It really means a lot to me.")
    c.close()
```

Note: The "`host = "172.31.26.54`" in the client code is because the server code prints (in line 5) "`ip-172-31-26-54`" when run.

When I run the server code, then change in the client `host` to `socket.gethostname()` and run it on the server, it works perfectly. But when I run the code on different machines, the client just prints "Attempting to connect..." and gets stuck.

Edit: I just tried it using the public ip instead of the private ip. That didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe a network filter like firewall or security-groups if running on cloud environment

Comment: "ip-172-31-26-54" - that's the host name and even though it looks like an ipv4 address, that doesn't mean that its right. On the server, use `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` or whatever works for your system to see what the real address is.

Comment: It works perfectly on my machine, you code. The only difference was I did bind `0.0.0.0` as hostname. Be aware, `0.0.0.0` listens on all adaptors, someting you may not want. Alternatively, you can use `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Luke ... with the caveat that `127.0.0.1` is the internal loopback address and isn't visible to external machines.

Comment: On the server side, `print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))` - it may be resolving to a loopback address.

Comment: @tdelaney trust me I've worked with it before I mean `bind('127.0.0.1',PORT)` not `connect('127.0.0.1',PORT)` I am no amateur. With `connect` you can just `gethostbyname` or find the IP manually.

Comment: @Luke - `bind('127.0.0.1',PORT)` binds to the local loopback address (if the server isn't using a different address like 127.0.1.1) and it isn't visible to external clients. OP wants to connect from other computers so its not a good choice.

Comment: @tdelaney Sure enter `0.0.0.0` with no dmz and forward port.

Comment: @tdelaney `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` is perfect.

Comment: @Luke - why do you think its perfect? For me right now, it returns `127.0.1.1` because I'm on a dhcp network that doesn't accept my hostname advertisement. Most home and public networks behave this way. Its pretty common for address resolution of the local host to go to a loopback address and skip the adapter stack even if names are right. The hope with the `gethostbyname` trick is that you talk to an external authorative DNS server that knows your address, but that is not a sure thing, especially in environments where there is no authorative dns server.